# random access to tuple-values in vector of tuples

Tags: c++, vector, tuples

I have the following:

```
template<typename...T> struct VTS : private std::vector<std::tuple<T...> >
{ 
    typedef std::vector<std::tuple<T...> > VT;
    typedef std::tuple<T...> TUP;
    ...
    //I want to do..
    auto getvalue(size_t vidx, size_t tidx)
    {
         return std::get<tidx>(VT::at(vidx));
    }
};
```

The above does not work because `std::get<>` requires `tidx` to be `constexpr`
How can I get `getvalue()` or something like it to work?

---

[answer to comment]
An example usage would be something like:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<myvts.size(); i++)
    for (size_t j=0; j<myvts.tupsize(); j++)
        std::cout << myvts.getvalue(i,j) << "\n";
```

for whatever relevance it may have. The problem is to get auto to work with getvalue() - if at all possible.
Whether `std::vector` is inherited or encapsulated is not relevant to the problem, although I understand and agree, it is here used as quick "on the same page" example.

---

To answer Hold & Hajo("tuple is the wrong choice here"):

The need is for a list of collections of different types, several different lists each with their own collections; what would you propose to do? tuple fits the bill since it can hold different types, what else is there?

Comment: you shouldn't use a tuple for that

Comment: @Tyker: neither here nor there - I'm investigating options and if I can get this to work it'll fit the bill... focus is on `getvalue()`

Comment: @slashmais You need to add information on where you use `getvalue`, or better, explain what you are trying to achieve in the end so we can propose alternative solutions.

Comment: Off-topic: You should not inherit `std::vector`. Standard containers are not made to be inherited properly, you should rather encapsulate it.

Comment: @Holt: given my use-case in the question ... would really appreciate a good solution

Comment: If the tuple contains different types, then `getvalue` *must* be a template, a function always has *exactly one* return type.

Answer (score 1):

You should not iterate over `tuple` that way, you may use `std::apply`, for example:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<T...> > v;

for (const auto& t : v) {
    std::apply([](const auto& ... args) { ((std::cout << args << "\n"), ...); }, t);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me as if you misunderstand a critical difference between templates and plain code. Templates are generated at compile time and are then fixed. Think of `std::tuple<T...>` as a struct. `std::tuple<int, 3>` is akin to

```
struct int_3
{
   int _1;
   int _2;
   int _3;
};
```

There is just no (good) way to access the elements in the tuple by an index **at runtime**. You have to know the index at compile time.

This is the reason why `get<>` tidx to be a `constexpr`: Because it needs to be known and resolved at compile time. Because of that, your idea simply will not work at all.

Take a step back and think about what you are actually trying to do.

Do you really want to calculate and pass tidx at runtime? If so, you need a different datatype entirely.

Or, if tidx is known at compile time, you have to rewrite your getvalue as a template member function. That would work (but be ugly, IMHO).

```
template <size_t tuple_index>
auto get_value(size_t vector_index)
{
   return std::get<tuple_index>(VT::at(vector_index));
}
```

You would call this like so

```
auto val=get_value<3>(4); // return tuple #3 from vector index 4
```

Answer the following question for yourself: Is the value of tidx always known at compile time or will tidx be calculated when the program is running?

If tidx will be calculated at runtime, tuple is the wrong choice here.

If the type of the elements of the tuple is not known at compile time (type erasure) you need to use "variants". You could store them like this:

```
std::vector<   std::vector<variant> > m_variant_list;
m_variant_list.at(vidx).at(tidx);
```

A good idea might be boost::any.

Comment: yes, knew that before I asked the question, but was(is?) hoping & wishing for what-shall-I-call-it: "late-binding templates"? - damn that would be nice!

Comment: " tuple is the wrong choice here" - need is for a list of collections of different types, several different lists each with their own collections; what would you propose to do? `tuple` fits the bill since it can hold different types, what else is there?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "late-binding-template". You need to read and understand a critical point about templates: Code is generated for them at compile time.

Comment: You could ask a new question: I need a vector of tuples of objects where the type of the object is not known until runtime. Something like this.